# Getting an error trying to play an audio file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to play a mp3 file in the same directory using pygame.mixer. Here is the code

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('tom.mp3')
mixer.music.set_volume(0.7)
mixer.music.play()
```

But I am getting this error and i am not able to rectify it. I have tried changing it to a .wav file, that did not work either.

ERROR:

```
 mixer.music.play()
pygame.error: mpg123_seek: Invalid RVA mode. (code 12)
```

I have no idea about audio in python. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
sound = mixer.Sound('tom.mp3')
sound.play()
```